# ZFC Axioms of Set Theory as stated by Thomas Jech

Tags: set-theory

I'll try to make this as short as I can. I'm just beginning to read Thomas Jech's Set Theory (3rd Millenium Edition) where he starts with the axioms of ZFC. Pardon the naivete of my question that follows, but some of these axioms sound vague to me. Take the Axiom of Separation:  If $P$ is a property with parameter $p$, then ***for any $X$***, there exists a ***set $Y$*** $= \{u \in X : P(u,p)\}$.

The same with Axiom of Power Sets: ***For any $X$***, there exists a ***set $Y$*** of the subsets of $X$.

The key thing I have an issue with is that this "***any $X$***" is vague and does not help the reader make sense of the axioms. What is $X$ to be? It's not a trivial question when you consider the assertions these axioms make: namely, that the objects $Y$ in my two examples above are actually ***sets*** (and thus do not belong to the cesspool of proper classes that tend to breed those Russell-type paradoxes).

For example, in the power set axiom, since there are no restrictions on $X$, can I take $X$ to be a proper class? If so, this axiom tells me that the power set of $X$ (which has strictly larger cardinality than $X$ itself) is a set and not a proper class. How is that to be?

Comment: Are you familiar with the syntax and semantics of first-order logic?

Comment: @Noah Schweber:   Yes, very familiar. My question does not come from ignorance of universal quantifiers.

Comment: If you're familiar with first order logic the situation is analogous to the axioms of groups, we just say $\forall x\forall y\forall (z (x+y)+z=x+(y+z))$, without the need to specify that $x,y,z$ range over "elements of groups". In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we write axioms $\forall x(\cdots)$ without the need to specify that $x$ ranges over "sets"

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti: So as not to be repetitive, please read my comment to spaceisdarkgreen's response below.

Comment: When you state the axioms of $\mathsf ZFC$ you're already working in a metatheory which is itself a set theory (usually $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself), look at the definition of a model: "a model is **a set** with blablabla...". You should think about $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as "just" another first order theory, rather than something that should magically be imbued with meaning from no previous knowledge

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti: The problem with your last two comments is that in the definion of a group, before proceeding to the formula you wrote, a textbook will state that a group is a set of elements that satisfy the formulas that follow ….   Similarly with the definition of a model,  it is a "set" whose elements have whatever structure that satisfies this, this, and that. In both these cases, I know what set is because I've been through the study of ZFC: A set is whatever sastisfies all the axioms of ZFC. But in the ZFC axioms themselves, you can't use a set at the outset.

Comment: The axioms of set theory are not to *define* sets any more than, in the group theoretic example, we are defining what a group element is. We're stating the conditions that we want to be true in a set-theoretic universe. A theory is *not* merely a by-product of a set with some structure.

Comment: In ZFC  a set is what u're trying to describe. Put another way, before the ZFC axioms I don't know any more about sets than someone who's never seen a chessboard before would know about a bishop. And even when if you were to show him a bishop he wouldn't care about what it looks like. He'd want to know what you can do with it in the field.

Comment: The issue is that not only you can use a set at the outset, you pretty much must do so!

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti:  Umm, No.  At the outset you can use any object X (and we hope that it will be a set as described by the axioms), but that object X runs the risk of being a proper class. That is what I take Jech's "any X" to mean. I'm pretty sure that is what he means and that there is some flaw in my reasoning about the Power Set Axiom example in the original question.

Comment: Quantifiers only range over the domain of discourse, and in set theory, that domain is *the universe of sets*. In the ontology of ZFC, there is no such thing as a proper class for it to range over; if an object is in the range of the quantifier, *it is a set*.

Comment: @Malice Vindrine: This is the problem with ZFC as opposed to any other theories. The domain (the universe of sets) is what the axioms describe. It does not precede the axioms.   Before the ZFC axioms, I believe the domain is the universe of classes, not all of which are sets (as is shown by Russell's paradox). The axioms are an attempt to separate those classes that are sets from those that are not (if you don't want to use the phrase 'proper class').

Comment: I understand that that's what you're thinking, but that's simply not the case. Just like the quantifiers in a group theoretic statement do *not* range over the entire universe of sets and distinguish which are group elements and which are not; the quantifiers in a group theoretic statement range only over the elements of the group. You've developed a very misleading picture of what theories actually do.

Comment: @Malice Vindrine: I'm not sure I can speak for statements in group theory, but I'm quite sure I don't have a misleading picture of what Axiomatic Set Theory does. The whole reason for having the ZFC axioms is so that we can count on one fact: there will be no contradictions of the type of Russell's paradox provided that the objects we're working with have been shown to satisfy the ZFC axioms (i.e. they have been shown to be sets).

Comment: @marcus66502 I think you need to seriously consider the possibility that you *do* have a misleading picture of what axiomatic set theory does. (Back and composing my followup, as promised).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Again, I'm being asked to seriously consider the possibility that the notion of set exists before the axioms that are there to make it precise. If I could already distinguish a "set" from all those other frightful things out there then why exactly have ZFC axioms?

Comment: A) ZFC does not guarantee us any such thing, and B) it does *not* pick out the "safe" classes from a prior universe of proper classes, it tells us what holds *internally to the universe of sets*. ZFC is a first order theory like any other, and if you understand the semantics for first order theories, then you should know the quantifiers do not do what you're trying to say they do.

Comment: Surely one way to make clear the idea of a "set" is to make clear what you can infer from a statement about sets--i.e. our ability to prove facts about sets from other facts about sets. A formal theory of sets does this, and ultimately we use our capacities as natural language users to figure out what these formal sentences *mean*; it's a remarkable bonus that we can do all the things we can do with *models* of such discourse, but the models are not the alpha and omega of theories.

Comment: In the formal language of set theory in which the axioms are written, the words "set" and "class" do not occur. These words are heuristic or intuitive guides to what we hope to be doing. You cannot make a statement such as   "If X is a set then..." in the formal language  of set theory.

Comment: Related on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300753/circular-or-missing-definition-in-set-theory

Comment: @KeyFlex: ***Really***??? You edited just *two* variables into `$` signs? You're *that* badge hungry that you won't even spend the extra three minutes to edit this post properly???

Answer (score 8):

In ZFC the domain of discourse is all sets. So when we say 'for all $X$' we mean for all sets $X$. So the power set axiom can be written in more detail as "for every set $X$ there is a set $P(X),$ whose elements are all sets that are subsets of $X.$"

(What 'all' sets means is a different can of worms and varies from model to model. But in any event, proper classes are not sets by definition, so are not included. In fact they can't be directly expressed as objects in ZFC's language. Rather, they are talked about indirectly, via formulas. So a class is just a formula, whose extension may or may not correspond to a set.)

**Edit** (In response to your comments)

It is wrong to think of the ZFC axioms as 'defining what a set is' although I can see why you might be under that impression since most of the axioms essentially tell you how to define new sets from previously defined ones. Rather, the ZFC axioms define what a set theoretical *universe* is, in that a set theoretical universe is a collection of objects and a membership relation $\in$ on those objects for which the axioms hold.

Although we certainly want such a theory to be consistent, and paradox avoidance is what motivated the restricted form of comprehension that ZFC has, it's also important to realize that ZFC makes some 'arbitrary' choices that have nothing to do with paradox avoidance. For instance, the axiom of extensionality implies that everything in our universe is a set and, for instance, there are no 'pure elements' (usually called urelements) that are not set-like in nature. (It does so by implying that the empty set is the only thing that doesn't contain anything else.) Also, the axiom of foundation guarantees that there are no strange sets that contain themselves, e.g. so-called Quine atoms obeying an equation like $x=\{x\},$ which are not inherently paradoxical despite not being as natural as urelements and superficially smelling like Russell's paradox. It is useful since it implies that the universe of sets is arranged in a [Von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) The other axioms (including perhaps choice) are less arbitrary, in the sense that they formalize our intuition from naive set theory of what kinds of sets we should be able to define based on others.

It is also  important to note that ZFC is not a full characterization of a unique universe of sets. For instance, you have probably heard that the continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC and that the axiom of choice is independent of ZF. This means that there are models of ZF/C that differ on these questions, and thus we haven't uniquely specified a universe of sets.

(In fact we could have never hoped to do anything close to this in a first order theory, with results like Lowenheim-Skolem. And yet if we try to move to a second order theory we run into another problem that we need set theory in our metatheory so set theoretical questions our theory 'answers' may well depend on what the answer is in the metatheory.)

As other have noted in the comments, this is not a lot different from how we usually proceed in axiomatizing math. The group axioms don't 'define what a group element is', they tell you the properties all groups have (and note there are many groups just as there are many models of ZFC). Same goes for the axiomatization of any type of mathematical object. Sometimes, as in the second order Peano axioms, there is only one model (up to isomorphism) obeying them, but that is a rare case.

This issue of circularity that you bring up is called [impredicativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity) and a lot has been written about it. Essentially, it is the problem of circularity when the definition of an object involves quantifying over a universe containing that object. So for instance, when you define the empty set as 'the set that doesn't contain anything,' this definition includes an implicit clause that the empty set doesn't contain the empty set, and thus seems to require we know what the empty set is prior to our defining the empty set. Of course this is a silly example since it's reasonably clear that the notion of the empty set is self-consistent (see also the example of 'the tallest person in the room' from the Wikipedia page), so not all impredicative definitions are problematic.

Russell originally believed impredicativity was the ultimate source of his paradox and thus something that should be eliminated from formal foundations mathematics. However he was unable to develop mathematics satisfactorily on a predicative basis. There have been more successful attempts since then, but in general, much of classical mathematics is either impossible or intolerably difficult to develop only using predicative definitions. (Compare to the situation with constructive mathematics.)

Still, like constructivity, predicativity has its proponents, and consensus seems to be that it is at least something worth paying attention to as an organizing principle. For instance, in a second order theory, once can restrict comprehension principles to only apply to predicative formulas (i.e. ones that do not quantify over properties). ZFC is "hopelessly" impredicative, in the sense that if you think predicativity is a requirement in some sense, you probably reject ZFC foundations. You are correct to highlight the power set axiom as a weak point here, and there is also essential impredicativity in the separation and replacement axioms. ([Kripke-Platek set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory) (which is often viewed as a predicative fragment of ZFC) eliminates power set and choice and restricts both separation and replacement.

Notice, however, according to the the view I expressed at the outset (which is the view Jech and the majority of modern set theorists hold), impredicativity is *not* a problem. To be a little more specific, way to think about it is we have a (perhaps hypothetical) collection $V$ of objects related by the membership relation $\in$ that obey the ZFC axioms. This universe is fixed (though we don't necessarily specify it fully other than that it obeys the ZFC axioms). Then it makes sense that the axioms say 'for all sets, yada yada'. They are true statements about this universe of sets. They do tell us some that sets with certain properties have to exist and for certain properties (like $\forall x (x=x)$ by Cantor's paradox) there can't be a set with that extension, but again, this is a *description* of the universe.

If the axioms simply describe a universe of sets rather than 'building one from the ground up', then impredicative definitions pose no risk. It's just like the example with the tallest person in the room: if you really have a room with some people in it and aren't defining the people in the room into existence, there can't be any problems brought on by the circularity here. This isn't philosophically bulletproof since of course who says these set theoretical universes even exist, but still, given the difficulties with predicative mathematics and the general belief amongst set theorists that ZFC is consistent and that set theoretical universes either really exist in some sense, or are at least worth reasoning about as hypothetical objects, it is the prevailing attitude.

The idea that taking a Platonist view of the domain makes predicativity less of a concern leads readily to the idea of relative predicativity, where certain objects are taken to 'exist at the outset' and everything else is defined predicatively. An example that came up in the comments was the constructible universe $L$. If you are given the ordinals, $L$ is a completely predicative construction where every set (except the ordinals you start with) can be regarded as 'defined into existence' from the bottom up.

**Edit 2**
This is already overlong and a bit unfocused (though I think the commenters-- including a few professional logicians in case authority makes a difference-- have done a really good job of hammering home the main take-aways) but I thought it would be useful to actually spell out how the definition of the power set should be thought of here.

First of all, there is the subset property $y\subseteq x$ which is an abbreviation for $\forall z (z\in y \to z\in x),$ which hopefully already seemed sharp and unproblematic here. We don't even really quantify over 'all sets', just the elements of $y.$ Then, the power set axiom says $$\forall x \exists!z \forall u (u\in z \leftrightarrow u \subseteq x)$$ which *informs* us we are *assuming* that a set theoretical universe has, for any set $x,$ a unique power set $z$ whose elements are exactly those sets $u$ that obey the relation $u\subseteq x$ (just as we assume a group has an identity element with certain properties).

(Note we don't actually have to put all this in the axiom... for instance extensionality already guarantees the uniqueness part, and if we wish, we can weaken the $\leftrightarrow$ to a $\leftarrow$ and use subset comprehension to pick up the slack.)

Now, since we know there is a unique set with this property, we can define an operation $\mathcal P:V\to V$ such that given a set $x,$ $\mathcal P(x)$ is the unique set with this property. So we have argued that within any set-theortical universe, that this operation is well-defined and thus we have a power set for every set.

If you are a bit unsatisfied and think it's tautoglogical and we rigged that to happen, well, that's the point of the power set axiom. It's a thing that guarantees the existence of a power set for every set.

Comment: I don't think so. The whole point of Axiomatic Set Theory is to provide a framework for proving that a certain object is a "set", as opposed to something else (possibly a proper class), so the language used in expressing these axioms is crucial here.   I don't know what a set is  outside of what these axioms tell me, and likewise I don't know how to create a set outside of the rules prescribed by these axioms (take unions, pairs, etc). If you read through most of the proofs in Jech's book you'll notice that their key result is that the object constructed is actually a set (the "wonder" object)

Comment: @marcus66502 'you don't think so' with regard to what? I don't think anything I've said here is controversial, but I'm not sure what you are disagreeing with.

Comment: When he says "for any X" he does not mean "for all sets X". That would be circular. We don't yet know sets before stating the axioms. More precisely, the only thing I know about sets is what's been stated about them from the axioms.

Comment: @marcus66502 I agree this is confusing and I see the apparently circularity, but I assure you that is exactly what he means. I'm a little busy at this exact moment but I will elaborate in a few minutes if someone else doesn't get to it first.

Comment: @marcus66502 "The whole point of Axiomatic Set Theory is to provide a framework for proving that a certain object is a "set"" No. The whole point of axiomatic set theory is to provide a framework for describing how sets behave. Amongst other things, this lets us prove that certain formulas don't define sets (that is, that certain classes are proper classes), but the axioms need to be understood as *describing a (hypothetical) existing universe* rather than trying to create one from scratch. That's why quantifiers range over all sets.

Comment: ... exactly the same way that the axioms of a group don't provide a framework for telling whether any particular object is a "group element".  The group axioms tell whether a collection of elements together with an operation form a group; the ZFC axioms tell whether a collection of objects together with a membership relation form a model of ZFC.  When we talk about a model of ZFC, we have to do so in some metatheory (which could also be ZFC, or it could be some other set theory, or even a theory like second order arithmetic).

Comment: @Noah I wouldn't be able to say what "The whole point of axiomatic set theory is".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, it seems it's come a long way since 1908

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That's a good point, I was using the same language to emphasize the distinction but you're right that that's improper.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  With regard to your comment about the definition of the empty set as the set that doesn't contain anything, actually in Jech's text this is done the safe way: the empty set is naturally the set resulting from a formula which no object could possibly satisfy  such as  'x is not equal to x'.  He then establishes that the class of objects satisfying this formula is actually a set, the empty set. From then on we have a way of creating new sets (the natural numbers, etc.) using the axioms for unions, pairings, power sets etc.

Comment: (continued)  My point in my previous comments is that outside of this chain of "set creation" (i.e. starting from the empty set and using the axioms), I wouldn't know how to create sets any other way. Remember, I no longer have intuition to guide me in forming sets, which is just my way of saying I know nothing about sets other than what the axioms say about them. A priori, I'm completely blind.

Comment: @marcus66502  "My point in my previous comments is that outside of this chain of "set creation" (i.e. starting from the empty set and using the axioms), I wouldn't know how to create sets any other way." -- You should skip ahead to the chapter on the axiom of constructibility in Jech.

Comment: @marcus I don’t see how that’s so different. The power set of $x$ is the set of all sets $y$ with the property that $y\subseteq x$ just like the empty set is the set of all sets $y$ with the property that $y\ne y.$ The former exists (ie is a set) by the power set axiom. The latter exists by the empty set axiom (which thanks to subset comprehension can be weakened to ‘there exists a set’ so is redundant with that and the axiom of infinity or a logical axiom that the universe is nonempty, which is why Jech doesn’t need to include it). They seem completely analogous to me.

Comment: @marcus to the second point, I feel like a lot have people have told you that’s not the way to think about it. If you have a definition for a prospective set (which is not the same thing as a class comprehension though you can use a class comprehension to make a definition) then you ask things like “Does ZFC prove this set exists, that it doesn’t exist, or is its existence consistent with ZFC but unprovable.”

Comment: @marcus I should really talk of properties instead of definitions, e.g. “ZFC proves there is a unique set with this property.” Of course if the property is that its *elements* are characterized by a property, as in a comprehension, existence implies uniqueness by the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: @marcus66502 A couple more points. First, note that you won't actually get very many sets creating them in the way you say. In fact you have at best a (potentially) countably infinite number of sets you can get here, since we only have a countable vocabulary. Not enough. Perhaps you're imagining some transfinite iteration that gets you all the sets (which as Not Mike alludes to, is a similar idea to the constructible hierarchy). Well, for that you need ordinals and where are you going to get those?

Comment: @marcus66502 Noah opened up this thread asking about your familiarity with syntax and semantics of first order logic and I could have probably saved myself some typing by cutting more closely to what (I think) he was getting at there. The semantics of a first order theory always is an interpretation consisting of a logically prior universe things come from along with an interpretation of the language. We talk about this universe in the metatheory to define whether statements in the language are true or false in the interpretation.

Comment: @marcus66502 Note since semantics involves a lot of reasoning about collections of elements, we need some kind of set concept in the metatheory. This isn't peculiar to set theory, rather to the semantics of first order logic in general. So isn't this circular since we need to understand sets to reason about the semantics of set theory?

Comment: @marcus66502 Yes and no. It might be helpful to view the *syntax* of FOL as coming to the rescue here. The notion of what constitutes a formal proof in ZFC just formally checking the validity of proofs which is a completely finitary thing we could program a computer to do. So if we just say our metatheory is ZFC, we have no (or less, anyway) philosophical problems understanding what it means for us to prove things about the semantics of set theory in ZFC. This doesn't eliminate a conceptual circularity here (but all things must eventually be circular) but it does help clarify things

Comment: @marcus66502 (sorry, I know this is a lot... I've been traveling so writing in little spurts which tends to make it more disorganized... but hopefully it's still helpful. Incidentally, I see Eric linked a MO post above wherein Noah's answer says something pretty similar to my last couple comments there, though probably better put (so I could have really saved some typing). There's other good stuff on that thread too.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: "note that you won't actually get very many sets creating them in the way you say. … Perhaps you're imagining some transfinite iteration that gets you all the sets … Well, for that you need ordinals and where are you going to get those?"    No, No.  You can get all the ordinals in this way by going as far as your heart desires. Start with the empty set and denote it 0. Then define the ordinal n to be the set containing the ordinals 1 through n-1. This will get you all finite ordinals. Then define omega as the set containing all finite ordinals and keep going buddy.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  I don't have a problem with getting the whole zoo of ordinals in this way. I have a problem with the inherent vagueness of the X in the statements of the Axiom of Separation, Axiom of Replacement, Axiom of Union, and Axiom of Power Sets. I don't think Jech means "for any set X", otherwise he would have said that rather than "for any X".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: The language used in the statement of axioms is crucial here, Why? Because if you read the (false) Axiom of Comprehension and its weaker version, the Axiom of Separation you'll see that the only key difference is that the latter states "for any X" while the former states "for any SET X". Somehow this difference is supposed to eliminate paradoxes of the Russell type but I fail to understand how? Moreover, using "for any X" rather than "for any set X" admits proper classes into the discussion, hardly helpful for Power Set and Union Axioms.

Comment: If we take a union of a collection of sets "indexed by a proper class"  as they would say in undergraduate mathematics, I have trouble seeing how the result would be a set (and not another frightening proper class).

Comment: @marcus I could say more about the issue with the ordinals, and about how weakening to subset comprehension (which is another term for ZFC’s separation axiom, not the inconsistent unrestricted comprehension btw) fixes Russell’s paradox, but I don’t see the point since you are still trying to tell me ‘what Jech means’. There are legitimate philosophical debates to have about set theory, but that Jech means ‘all sets $X$’, not ‘all classes’ or ‘all anything else’ when he quantifies over ‘all $X$’ is not up for debate, as should be evident from the unanimous response you received.

Comment: @marcus I know this because Jech is a mainstream set theorist and although I am far from an expert, I’ve taken the time to study the basics of how set theorists think about the concepts. I suggest you do the same. Set theory is thorny conceptually so they have taken pains to think clearly and have developed a consensus about some things... I am just relaying this. (FWIW I find Kunen’s 1980 book explains conceptual issues more thoroughly than Jech’s). Also note that there are class set theories like NBG and Morse Kelly in which ‘all $X’ means ‘all classes’, unlike the case in ZFC.

Comment: @marcus but even if you were willing to take the hint here, this is hardly the forum to correct all of the understandable confusion you’re having. Just takes some time and effort with a textbook or two, and reading some MSE and MO content. And it will be helpful if you are open to adjusting your thinking to how set theorists think rather than trying to cling to your initial impression of how the subject should work.